# finding out team number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A supervisor has to select a three-member project team from among her 12 employees. Unfortunately, two of the employees cannot work together on the same team. With this restriction, how many different teams can she form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are how many possible ways of forming a team without any restriction? The answer is $\binom{12}{3}$. Out of these how many are undesirable? They are $10$ in number because if the two employees are already selected in an undesirable team, then any of the remaining $10$ may join to complete the team.

Hence there are $\binom{12}{3}-10$ different teams possible.

Comment: **They are 10 in number because if the two employees are already selected in an undesirable team, then any of the remaining 10 may join to complete the team.**
Can you elaborate this please?

Comment: Out of 12 people to form an undesirable team we first select the two people which can't work together. Obviously there is only one way to select these two. Now out of the remaining 10 people we need to pick one. There are $\binom{10}{1}=10$ ways to do that and each such way yields an undesirable team. Hence an undesirable team may be selected in $1\times 10=10$ ways.